# Get number of retries from Wait Until Keyword Succeeds

Tags: robotframework, built-in

We are using Robot Framework to test an rather error prone component, that we cannot debug. This component behaves somewhat erratic, so that in several places we are using the keyword `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  10x  1s   Connect Via SSH` to try several times even though it should work on the first try.

No, it would be great to obtain the number of retries of the keyword, so that it should issue a warning `Log` message in case more than one retry was necessary.

The following snippet illustrates what I wanted to achieve:

```
${result}   ${noRetries}=   Wait Until Keyword Suceeds with Return   10x   1s   Connect Via SSH
Run Keyword If   ${noRetries}>1     Log   ${noRetries} were necessary for Connect Via SSH   level=WARN
```

Is there a way to achieve this readily with Robot Framework?

Comment: Not with the vanilla keyword - it returns only the result of the called keyword; it in fact does: `return self.run_keyword(name, *args)`, inside a try-catch block. You might want to create a custom keyword or python method that does return you both the result(s) and the retry count.

Answer (score 2):

I would create higher level keyword containing the keyword which is flaky and increment tries within that.

**Edit.** updated answer with custom library example (option B)

Library solution makes Robot file much cleaner, because complexity is transferred to the Python side.

**option A.**

Using Robot Framework Test Variable.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup    Set Test Variable  ${KW_RUNS}  ${0}

*** Keywords ***
Flaky Keyword
    Set Test Variable  ${KW_RUNS}   ${KW_RUNS+1}
    Connect Via SSH

*** Test Cases ***
Trying something here
    ${result}   Wait Until Keyword Succeeds   10   1s   Flaky Keyword
    Run Keyword If   ${KW_RUNS}>1     Log   ${KW_RUNS} were necessary for Connect Via SSH   level=WARN
```

**option B.**

Using Robot Framework custom library.

*flakylib.py*

```
import time
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

KW_RUNS = 0


def custom_kw_runner(name, *args):
    global KW_RUNS
    KW_RUNS += 1
    return BuiltIn().run_keyword_and_return_status(name, *args)


def run_flaky_kw(retries=10, interval=1, name="", *args):
    global KW_RUNS
    KW_RUNS = 0
    status = False
    for _ in range(retries):
        status = custom_kw_runner(name, *args)
        if bool(status):
            break
        time.sleep(interval)
    if not bool(status):
        raise AssertionError(
            f"Keyword '{name}' failed after retrying for {retries*interval} seconds."
        )
    if bool(status) and KW_RUNS > 1:
        BuiltIn().log(f"{KW_RUNS} runs were necessary for '{name}'", level="WARN")
    return status, KW_RUNS
```

*withlib.robot*

```
*** Settings ***
Library  flakylib.py


*** Test Cases ***
Trying something here
    ${status}  ${runs}=  Run Flaky KW  name=Connect Via SSH
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm using Wait Until Keyword Succeeds quite often. Maybe there is also a more generic solution, but I really don't know how to do it. Still many thanks for your solution, it is at least working. :-)

Comment: Good that it works :) Another solution would be making your own customlibrary with a keyword which would basically do the things I posted in my example.

Comment: With option 2 the caller will not get back the return value(s) of the called keyword, which may be needed in a lot of cases. The most solid approach would be to reimplement the `wait_until_keyword_succeeds` keyword but also return the retries count.